# PHP mysqlnd/MySQL version

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

I've got an old machine running PHP 5.3.8 & MySQL 5.5.23 (found via mysql's "select version()" command). However, PHP's mysqlnd driver indicates MySQL 5.0.8. What gives?

I know PHP on this machine needs to be upgraded, could that be the issue? Does mysqlnd get upgraded to support "newer" MySQL versions when PHP is upgraded? Thanks!

Comment: it should, but you can download latest version of driver and update it only.. in most case all you need to do is just replace the files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found the answer. mysqlnd version numbers are not in line with mysql version numbers. More information on php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.plugin.obtaining.php

It looks like mysqlnd is not hooked up to a specific mysql version. For instance: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c#L2799